# Function keys require Fn modifer. How can I make them default?

Tags: keyboard, windows-vista, dell-studio

On my Dell Studio 15, the function keys, by default, do things like switch the radio on/off or change the brightness or sound. To use them as function keys I have to hold down the Fn modifier.

I use function keys as function keys a lot more often than I want to change the volume or brightness.

Am I missing an obvious setting somewhere in the control panel (Vista Uber Extreme Something)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be a BIOS setting to modify this behavior:

Advanced -> Function Key Behavior -> Function Key First

Comment: Doh! Didn't think of the BIOS settings. New computer and all. I'll check it next time I restart.

Answer (score 5):

This setting can also be changed through the Windows Mobility Center, look for the "Function Key Row" setting.

Comment: According to a deleted post: the BIOS changes the default, and the Windows Mobility Center (WIN+X) allows toggle. And apparently some computers might fail to honor the default from the BIOS.

Comment: As of windows 8.1, I'm not seeing the 'Function Key Row' in the Mobility Center.  Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

This question is also answered here: https://superuser.com/a/1219207/59508

Often the ESC key will have a 'function lock' icon which looks like a padlock. Press the 'FN' select key and ESC and it switches the function keys to behave as function keys.