# Function keys on Dell laptop requires Fn+F1-F12 (default is multimedia/oem key)

Tags: laptop, keyboard, function-keys

In most dell laptop (e.g. *Studio 1555*, *Inspiron 1545*, *Inspiron 3000*, *Inspiron N5010* etc) the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys at the top of the keyboard are dual function with Multimedia/OEM keys such as volume and screen brightness etc. The problem is, is that the Multimedia/OEM keys are the default, and you have to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to get the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> key to work.

For example, this means you have to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close a window, instead of the regular <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. This is really annoying. Is there a way to reverse the default functions of the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys in Windows?

Ideally this is possible without some kind of third party hotkey manager.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [Whirlpool's](http://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/?tag=Dell_Studio_1555) KB article on the Dell Studio 1555:

> The media buttons are switched on by default instead of the F keys so to perform a task such as closing a window (Alt-F4), you are required to press Alt-Fn-F4. **To reverse this function, it is necessary to go into the BIOS.**

Comment: There it is, it's called "Function Key Behavior". Thanks!

Comment: It's now called `Fn Lock Disable` in `POST Behavior`

Answer (score 57):

Often the ESC key will have a 'function lock' icon which looks like a padlock.
Press the 'FN' select key and ESC and it switches the function keys to behave as function keys.

Comment: This is the most correct and up-to-date answer

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: Especially useful if your laptop is managed by an IT department and you can't get to the BIOS.  Hit FN/ESC every boot...

Comment: This also works for external keyboard.

Comment: This is the correct answers - as pointed out in [this page](https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Function-keys-changing-volume-and-other-stuff/td-p/7659070#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20you%20can%20often%20change%20this%20setting%20right%20on%20the%20keyboard%20itself%20via%20the%20Fn%20Lock%20key%20or%20a%20hidden%20Fn%20Lock%20shortcut.) too - `In general, you can often change this setting right on the keyboard itself via the Fn Lock key or a hidden Fn Lock shortcut`

Answer (score 4):

On Dell XPS 13 9370 it's depends on the BIOS settings. See the picture below.

You have three options:

1. With "Fn Lock" you can toggle between Functions and Media keys with Fn+Esc.
2. With "Lock mode disable" you can use F1-12 keys as Media keys.
3. With "Lock mode enabled" you can use F1-12 keys as Functions keys.

[image: Fn Lock Options]

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, I have been using a Studio 1555 with Vista 64bit for the last 6 months.

This setting does not appear in the Windows Mobility Center on my system, so I needed to change the setting in BIOS by pressing F2 at boot (no need to press fn F2, even when the keys behave as media keys in Windows). Occasionally, this setting appears to revet and I need to set the option again in the BIOS.

As noted above, perhaps there is some key combination to change the behaviour. I cannot explain why the keys reverted back to their media function by default.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's ...

> shift + numlock

My laptop is at home, so I can't test it.

Per comment:  [Check out this thread](http://en.community.dell.com/forums/p/19283278/19514803.aspx).  It indicates there is a BIOS setting.

Comment: There is no numlock key. There's no number pad either (even as a Fn alternative behind other keys, as my other Dell laptop has)

Answer (score 0):

You set the media keys in the bios from media to function.  It will toggle the Fn keys to the top and media where you hold the Fn key.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for Windows Mobility Center and change the option from there. No need to goto the BIOS.

Cheers

Comment: Nope, can't find that option. I use a Dell Studio 1555
http://i.imgur.com/TKNff.png

Answer (score 0):

For Dell
       Control Panel->Hardware and sound ->Adjust Commonly used Mobility Settings
Change the Function Key Row to 'Function Key' 
thats all

Comment: I don't see any such option in that tool.
http://i.imgur.com/TKNff.png

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible, but I cannot remember if it is a BIOS setting or software setting. It might just be a combo you push on your keyboard to turn function on or off by default. This can vary from laptop to laptop. On Apple macbook pro's the function is on by default. A dell laptop i had once was off by default and you could change it through a combo on the keyboard.

Comment: If you can't remember then you should post this as a comment instead of an answer.