# Making F1-F12 keys the default on Dell Inspiron 1545

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, dell-inspiron, fn-key

I've been given a laptop at work, a Dell Inspiron 1545, which I find pretty good, except for the `F1-F12` keys.

Being a programmer and a poweruser of several programs, I need to use them a lot, and here they are inverted, you need to press the `Fn` key to get access to them, and you get the volume up/down, brightness. wireless on/off stuff without pressing the `Fn`.
Is there any way (or hack) to make them the other way around?? `F1-F12` just by pressing the key, and the extra functions using `Fn`?

Its driving me crazy! Specially turning off the wireless when I want to rename stuff!

thanks!

Comment: Similar question for the Studio 1555: http://superuser.com/questions/22480/function-keys-on-dell-laptop-work-double-as-oem-keys

Comment: I didn't manage to actually do it, but shutting down the wireless in the middle of a download because I wanted to rename a file was my top fear until just now. Thanks for asking this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In many Dells there's a BIOS setting that will default Fn to on. There probably will be in the 1545.

Answer (score 13):

On my Dell XPS 15, it seems to be as simple as me accidentally pressing the Fn Lock button behind the Escape key. If you have this problem, simply hit Fn+Esc and it should revert back to normal, without having to go into the BIOS

Answer (score 12):

I found 2 solutions. The easiest:

Control Panel - Hardware and Sound - Adjust commonly used mobility settings - Fn Key Behavior

Comment: Thanks! This worked on my Inspiron too, and it's much simpler than mucking with the bios.

Comment: For some reason I'm not seeing the "Fn Key Behavior" settings on my Lenovo Edge (Windows 7 64 bit).

Answer (score 7):

I Could able to reverse the function of Fn key on my Dell by following steps provided your laptop has ESC and Fn key with lock shape on it.

Press Fn Key + ESC (Fn) Key

The functionality automatically gets toggled.

Comment: Yes, my keyboard has an icon there that looks like a keypad with the text FN on it. So this works.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is: Simply press (Fn+Esc) and that should fix it.

Comment: Does using Fn + Esc inverts the function buttons back?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reverse the function of `Fn` key on my Dell Studio 1555 machine following the steps described below. The steps should be pretty similar on your machine too.

1. Restart the machine
2. Keep pressing `F2` repeatedly to load boot menu
3. In 'boot' menu, go to `Advanced` tab by pressing `right/left` arrow key on your keyboard
4. Under the `Advanced` tab, reach the option named `Function key behavior` by pressing `down`arrow key
5. When the option is highlighted, press `Enter key` and you will see a popup asking you to pick between `Multi media key first` and `Function key first`.
6. Pick `Function key first` by using `up/down` arrow key and press `Enter`
7. Press `F10` to *save and exit*.

Answer (score 0):

In Win7, you just go to Windows Mobility Center and change the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key behavior.

Comment: could u elaborate how to navigate to windows mobility center

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303 Control Panel - Windows Mobility Center